# How to get the offset of a view inside a ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, offset

There is a `ScrollView` and which has many children views. Is there any way to get the offset-y to the top of the ScrollView for every child?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hmmmm, not sure if this is the quickest, best way to do this, but if you get the view's location on screen, and you know the top of the ScrollView, you can calculate the offset of the view relative to the ScrollView. To get the position of a View in the screen:

```
int[] location = {0,0};
view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
```

`location[1]` has the Y value.  You will get negative values when the view is "above" the viewport.

Comment: What do you mean " top of the ScrollView"? the ScrollView's locationOnScreen?

Comment: when soft keypad is open, locations are changed. Any idea how to get the relative offset ?

Comment: Doesn't help OP if `view` if off screen.