# How to get Y axis in scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview, yaxis

I have a `ScrollView` which is programatically filled with `LinearLayouts`. When user changes between tabs, there is an ID stored in `sharedPreferences` which is used to get `LinearLayout` from hashMap. This Layout is then colored.

I also want to automatically scroll to this layout. Basically everything I want is "Y position" of given layout, so I can use it with `scrollView.scrollTo(0, Y);`

EDIT: somehow @basic 's solution is not working if layouts are added programatically. It scrolls, but it is far fro being accurate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the offset of a view inside a ScrollView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878997/how-to-get-the-offset-of-a-view-inside-a-scrollview)

Comment: Fml, how did I miss this thread... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

int scrollY = targetScrollView.getScrollY();

Comment: If I understand correctly this returns an int that represents where ScrollView is currently located? I need something that will give me Y position of some element (LinearLayout) that is located inside ScrollView.