# How to get the position inside a scrollview

Tags: java, android

How would you get the position of a TextView inside a scrollview then set it somewhere. For example, When TextView gets scrollY to 200, set TextView at (x,y)

Comment: Why is getting position required?

Comment: id like to create sticky headers but i do not want the headers to stick on the top instead id like it to stick about half way of a screen.

Comment: look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327087/how-to-get-the-current-y-offset-of-a-scrollview
   -   
and :
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878997/how-to-get-the-offset-of-a-view-inside-a-scrollview